# Does CreateFileMappingA write to file?

Tags: winapi, file-io

I was debugging some WinAPI application.
Right before the call to the function `CreateFileMappingA` the file's size was **0Kb**. Immediately after the call to the function, the file got around **200Kb**. I tried browsing the online Windows API documentation but didn't find anything (or not understand perhaps) whether a file write would occur after the function call. The `flProtect` parameter's value was `PAGE_READWRITE`.
I'd really like to know what the function really does, and especially why this write to the file.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about file mappings? Do you know what a file mapping is?

Comment: I read a bit about file mappings at Microsoft's online documentation. But I'm not an advanced programmer though :( , so sometimes concepts in a documentation are very hard to grasp for me.

Comment: File mapping is not a file. Does the function write to a file? No.

Comment: @RomanR. the file was written immediately after the call. So, don't I have the right to suspect?

Comment: @Toni The file is created, but not written to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand. But why the file size increased right after that function call? I was stepping through the code, right after the step which called CreateFileMappingA, the file size increased from 0 to 200Kb

Comment: Because the file mapping has to reserve the entire mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the function CreateFileMappingA was being called like this:
`CreateFileMappingA(fh, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0x336BC, "kll");`
According to the documentation, if the file size would be lower than the length the mapping targets, the file would be extended to fit the size.
So in my case, the file was just created.

```
fh = CreateFileA("file2.dat", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

So first, the file "file2.dat" would be created with write privileges. It would be 0Kb. Then, right after the call above to CreateFileMappingA, the file size would be 0x336BC bytes, or 206Kb.